# How to create a database from existing Database without any data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a database from existing one without taking any data from it (only schema). I know, I can create a script for this purpose using SQL Server Management Studio, but I need some transact SQL script doing this dynamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2012 copy database without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880974/sql-server-2012-copy-database-without-data) or [MS SQL 2008 - Create a copy of the database without the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912221/ms-sql-2008-create-a-copy-of-the-database-without-the-data) or probably more. If those don't answer your question, presumably because of _"I need some transact SQL script doing this dynamically"_, you should explain what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547/in-sql-server-how-do-i-generate-a-create-table-statement-for-a-given-table)

Comment: Thanks for your replay HoneyBadger but this is not what I want.I want something like procedure or a function

Comment: How about creating another database with no data.  Then, when you generate the script, use it to create a stored procedure in this db with no data.  You might need some input parameters for the database name and location.

Comment: Thanks, Dan Bracuk this is a great idea but later if I had some changes in the schema of Database I need recreate script and alter my procedure.I don't want this. I want this happen dynamically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this DBCC command: DBCC CLONEDATABASE
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177838/how-to-use-dbcc-clonedatabase-to-generate-a-schema-and-statistics-only

Comment: Thanks, PingPongOng .I think this is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Were I to need to do this, this is the approach I'd use. This is not a trivial task and the built in scripting tools are better suited as has been noted. However, this is the approach I'd use if I had to do it.

**Step 1 - Build tables** - Build a cursor for all your tables using:

```
SELECT object_schema_name([object_id]), [name]
FROM   [sys].[objects]
WHERE  [type] IN ( N'U' )
ORDER  BY [name];
```

Step through each and build dynamic SQL to "SELECT * INTO .. from ..

**Step 2 - Build procedures and functions** - Build a cursor using:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM   [sys].[objects]
WHERE  [type] IN ( N'P', N'TF', N'FN', N'IF' )
ORDER  BY [name];
```

Step through the objects and run "exec sp_helptext '.'" on each. Catenate the resultant lines using a COALESCE string builder and execute the result. Execute the result on your target database.

Comment: This is not what I want. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Databases, Tasks, Extract Data-tier Application:

[image]

After creating the dacpac file, right click on Databases and click on Deploy Data-tier Application

[image]

Select the dacpac created and it's done.